# How to make a reference to non escaping closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
class Child {
    var onClosureFromParent: ((Int) -> Void)?

    // Ok.
    func setupEscaping(onClosureFromParent: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        self.onClosureFromParent = onClosureFromParent
    }

    // Error: Assigning non-escaping parameter 'onClosureFromParent' to an @escaping closure
    func setupNonEscaping(onClosureFromParent: (Int) -> Void) {

        // FIXME:
        self.onClosureFromParent = onClosureFromParent
    }
}
```

I was wondering, how can I make a reference to non escaping closure?

Comment: You can't - Since that would allow the closure to escape.  You need to use the `@escaping` modifier as you have in the first function

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `onClosureFromParent` lives in the object and can be called anywhere then how can you make it non-escaping?

Comment: @Paulw11 said it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Official documentation:

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
>   an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.
>   When you declare a function that takes a closure as one of its
>   parameters, you can write @escaping before the parameter’s type to
>   indicate that the closure is allowed to escape.

Since the closure argument in the function, you are saving its reference and not executing it, it makes it implicit that this closure will not be executed within the scope of the function. Thus, you should allow it to escape.

```
func setupNonEscaping(onClosureFromParent: (Int) -> Void) {

       // Saving the reference, not executing it.
       // ie, It will be executed later on...
        self.onClosureFromParent = onClosureFromParent

    }
```

Somewhere in the code...

```
// The closure is executed later on, thus it should outlive the function lifescope.

let param = 10
 self.onClosureFromParent(param)
```